# Elegir una opción del select a través de una variable

Tags: angular, select, viewchild, elementref

Tengo un *select* creado pero quisiera que el texto que muestra por defecto pasarlo a través de una variable.

En el HTML tengo:

```
<select id="selectorSIP1" class="form-select" size="1" #selectorSIP1 (change)="funcSelectSIP($event,selectorSIP1.value,1)">  
<option value="" disabled selected hidden></option>
<option *ngFor="let sip of dataAPI['Interfaces']; let i=index" value={{sip.nombre}} >{{sip.realm}}</option>
</select>
```

Allí se ve que al principio hay un option con `value=""` que no se ve pero es el que queda por defecto.

En el TS uso *ViewChild* para hacer referencia al objeto:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit,  ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalService } from '../global.service';
import { dataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-diagrama-hijo',
  templateUrl: './diagrama-hijo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diagrama-hijo.component.css']
})
export class DiagramaHijoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() equipoD:string;
  @Input() posicionD:number;

  @ViewChild('selectorSIP1') selectorSIP1!: ElementRef;
```

En alguna parte del programa quiero que se muestre un determinado valor pero no funciona:

```
this.selectorSIP1.nativeElement.value(j['nombre']);
```

Tampoco así:

```
this.selectorSIP1.nativeElement.value=j['realm']
```

Agradezco desde ya vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Yo sugeriría que solo utilices `ViewChild` cuando de verdad lo necesites, lo genial de angular es poder hacer binding (algo con lo que otros lenguajes actualmente ya cuentan). ¿A que me refiero con esto? a que puedes utilizar una simple variable y asignarle el valor que quieras en cualquier parte del código sin la necesidad de que tengas que instanciar el objeto del *select* (en tu caso) y luego hacer un *getValue* para obtener el valor y hacer un *setValue* para mostrarlo en otro componente, te pongo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo de una manera mas sencilla.

Primeramente utlizaremos la directiva [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) al cual le pasaremos una variable que se llamará `seleccionado`, ésta es quien almacenará en este caso el valor seleccionado de tu *select*.

El *HTML* se vería de la siguiente forma:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="seleccionado">
    <option value="">Seleccione un registro</option>
    <option [value]="item.nombre" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.realm}}</option>
</select>
```

En el caso de *TypeScript*, instanciaremos la variable `seleccionado` que estamos utilizando en el *HTML* y una lista auxiliar para simular lo que tú tienes en tu código, seria algo así:

```
public seleccionado: string; // Este almacenará el value seleccionado de tu select
public list = [
  {id: 15645, nombre: 'Juan', realm: 'realm de Juan'},
  {id: 15643, nombre: 'Pepe', realm: 'realm de Pepe'},
  {id: 15664, nombre: 'Jorge', realm: 'realm de Jorge'}
];
```

Hasta aquí ya es funcional, ahora haremos una inyección en una etiqueta **`p`** para mostrar el valor seleccionado, para esto utilizaremos **`{{VARIABLE}}`** como bien utilizabas en los *value* de tu *select*, quedaría algo así:

```
<p>Item seleccionado: {{seleccionado}}</p>
```

Esto lo agregas donde sea que lo quieras mostrar en tu HTML.

Te darás cuenta que al cambiar de valor automáticamente cambiará también la inyección que hicimos en el *HTML*.

Finalmente podemos agregar un botón que cambie el valor seleccionado en el *select*:

```
<button (click)="seleccionado = 'Pepe'">Seleccionar Pepe</button>
```

Cuando quieras usar el valor seleccionado del *select* ya sea en *TypeScript* o *HTML* solo utilizarás la variable *seleccionado*.

Código completo del HTML, quedaría algo así:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="seleccionado">
    <option value="">Seleccione un registro</option>
    <option [value]="item.nombre" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.realm}}</option>
</select>

<p>Item seleccionado: {{seleccionado}}</p>

<button (click)="seleccionado = 'Pepe'">Seleccionar Pepe</button>
```